# ASP.NET MVC controller's action is executed again when jQuery's toggleClass() function is executed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

***EDIT 27.10.2016, 12:00***: i could figure out the reason of the following strange behavior:
it was simply because in the CSS, the path to a background-image that was used for some list-items of the menu was wrong. this caused the controller's action to trigger again. (!!!)

I have a controller with the following action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //get records from the database and pass them to the View
}
```

then in my view i display the following navigation (css classes are based on bootstrap):

```
<nav class="navigation_primary">
<ul class="nav nav-justified hidden-xs">
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="dropdown-toggle">StackOverflow</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">ASP.NET</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Then, in jQuery, I have the following code which is responsible for showing the children-entries when a parent is hovered with the mouse (e.g. show ASP.NET, C#, jQuery when StackOverflow is hovered).

```
//to open the primary navigation on mouseover
$(".dropdown").hover(

// open the dropdown by hover
function ()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
},

// close if the cursor goes outside the hover
function ()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
}
);
```

the strange thing is, that after i hover the menu item that has any children (in this case "StackOverflow which has the "dropdown" class), the whole Index() action i posted above is executed again.

does anybody see a reason for this strange behavior? in this case i don't understand why this interference between jQuery and ASP.NET MVC is happening.

***EDIT 27.10.2016, 11:00:*** i figured out that the conflict must depend by something else:
when i comment out the jQuery code i mentioned above and i replace it with the following CSS to reach the same behavior, then the controller's action is triggered too.

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{ display: block; }
```

Comment: Is this the whole code in your application? There is nothing that you have posted that would cause a post back. Are there any other event handlers? Are you using the bootstrap js?

Comment: You have   `function ()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
}` twice. Could that be causing problem?

Comment: @RobLang of course this is not the whole code, but just the part i considered relevant to explain this problem. there are many other event handlers and i'm also using bootstrap.js. but when i do something different in jQuery instead of toggling the css class (for example using the css() function to specify some css properties), the controller's action isn't fired anymore

Comment: @ElectricRouge no this isn't causing the problem. i specified this code twice according to https://api.jquery.com/hover/
the first one is the function to execute when the mouse pointer ***enters*** the element.
the second one is the function to execute when the mouse pointer ***leaves*** the element.

Comment: @RobLang see additional info in my edit above

Comment: In Chrome (or Firefox), open the tools window and find a list of event handlers. There must be an event firing to cause the request back to the server. Also check the Network tab and you can see at exactly what point it's triggered as it might not be the dropdown but the event might be bubbling to somewhere else.

Comment: I copypasted your code and added jquery and twitterbootsrap from cdn. And I don't have any strange behavior. It means the sending request happens somewhere else.

Comment: i solved the issue, see above. it was because an image-path used in css was wrong. eventhough, i didn't find any automatic error message in the console output of chrome's developer tools

Comment: Answer the question yourself and accept the answer or remove the question.

Comment: @Esko done, i'll leave it active in case that any other persons will encouter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i could figure out the reason of the following strange behavior: it was simply because in the CSS, the path to a background-image that was used for some list-items of the menu was wrong. this caused the controller's action to trigger again. (!!!)